# Customize WordPress Theme - WP / CSS Beginner

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me how can I decrease the amount of space in between the logo and navigation menu?

I have basic knowledge with Wordpress and HTML. But none about CSS. Maybe if anyone can point me to which file or section of line I should edit, that'd be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link to the site or some code. Every website is different.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.gdlr-navigation-wrapper .gdlr-main-menu > li > a {padding: 0px 20px 45px 20px;}
```

Into this:

```
.gdlr-navigation-wrapper .gdlr-main-menu > li > a {padding: 0px 30px 45px 30px;}
```